# Overflow hidden and display list-item on IE8+

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10

On Internet Explorer 8+, a display list-item element with an overflow "hidden" has an extra offset top.
Why ?

The element doesn't have any offset top on Chrome, Firefox, IE7.

[Jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/8d4XA/1/)
Comment / uncomment the list-item on LI element:
`li  {
    /*display: block;*/
}`

Chrome (no offset):
[image: Chrome]
IE10 (top offset in grey):
[image: IE10]

Comment: Are you using a reset.css or normalize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried removing the list-style on the li-element and it seemed to work.

```
li { list-style: none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8d4XA/10/), I removed the ul and li tags and replaced them with a paragraph tag.  You will also need to update the li and ul within the CSS.

This seems to take care of the block at the top of the screen in IE.

```
<body>
<div class="box">
    <p>
            <a href="#">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Silencium magistros ornat.
            </a>
    </p>
</div>
```

I'm not sure if this is what you were looking for, but to me it seems like the list item was creating the 'buffer' area.

I hope this helps.

Comment: @efusien - Hans Westman's solution is likely the route you want to take considering that you can keep the layout of the ul/li items.